# How to convert a string to an existing object in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How to call its methods if I only know the literal name of the existing object?

For example:

```
class Cat {
    def bark() {
        println "I am a cat."
    }
}

class Dog {
    def bark() {
        println "I am a dog."
    }
}

def cat = new Cat()
def dog = new Dog()

def animal = 'cat'
"${animal}".bark() // Error
```

As below, I only know the name of the animal (maybe cat or dog). How do I use this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `cat` and `dog` are defined as fields, you can use `this`:

```
this."${animal}".bark()
```

or

```
this[ animal ].bark()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def animals = [
  cat: new Cat(),
  dog: new Dog(),
]

def name = 'cat'
animals[name].bark()
```